# Is there a way to process a URL and form a new one with a substring (pattern) of the original?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have Ngninx installed on a server that provides images to another app. However, the images are stored in folders like...

- `/images/123456A/123456A0001.png`
- `/images/123456A/123456A0002.png`
- `/images/987654B/987654B0001.png`
- `/images/987654B/987654B0002.png`

Currently, it's configured to accept requests like...

- `GET IP/123456A/123456A0001.png`
- `GET IP/987654B/987654B0002.png`

---

The challenge here is that **I don't want to expose the internal structure when they make a GET request.** Is it possible to rewrite them internally like this...?

- `GET IP/123456A0001.png` ===>  `GET IP/123456A/123456A0001.png`
- `GET IP/987654B0002.png` ===> `GET IP/987654B/987654B0002.png`

The folder is part of the name of the file (numbers and one letter), but I can't figure out how to use a substring and form a new URL. I saw some examples but they just move parameters, and the text is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The `rewrite` directive can perform internal redirections. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

For example:

```
rewrite "^/(([^/]{7})[^/]{4}\.png)$" /$1/$2 last;
```

Alternatively, use a *regular expression* `location` together with a `try_files` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ "^/(([^/]{7})[^/]{4}\.png)$" {
    root /images;
    try_files /$1/$2 =404;
}
```